# How to improve my reading a file function and grabbing the data for better performance than file()?

Tags: php

My file is being recreated everyday at 00:00 and it's starting slowly during the day to add lines by lines as log file. The file is approximately 1 mb and with around 6,000 lines at the end of the day. So, it's not really small file. **My question is how I can make the script with better performance because `file()` is reading the whole file actually lines by lines, so what's a better way to do this?**
The file is as plain text in .txt format and these are an example lines from the file:

```
1,42,16, 201,stackoverflow_user, 1, 6762160, 39799, 9817242, 6762160, 39884, 10010545,stackoverflow_user, 2, 1351147, 1165, 483259, 1351147, 1115, 241630, 0 
1,46,27, 201,[stackoverflow_user | stackoverflow_userother], 1, 4078465, 286991, 1594830, 4078465, 287036, 1643156,stackoverflow_user, 2, 1357147, 1115, 241630, 1357147, 1065, 120815, 0
```

**My function:**

```
# read a file into an array
$lines = file('C:/path/to/file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

# flip our array over so the last lines of the file are first.
$lines = array_reverse($lines);
$n = 1;
$wanted = 21; # or however many lines you want.
$content = '';

foreach ($lines as $l) {
   # treat the data as comma-separated values
   $arr = explode(",", $l);
   # if col 5 has multiple values, take the first one
   if (preg_match("/\[(.+?) \|/", $arr[4], $matches)) {
       $arr[4] = $matches[1];
   }
   # is arr[4] the same as arr[12]?
   if ($arr[4] !== $arr[12]) {
       # these two are not equal, so use these values
       $data = array('rank-pos' => $n++, 'rank-name' => $arr[4], 'rank-dmuser' => $arr[12]);
       $content .= Template::Load('rankinguserdm-' . ($n % 2 == 1 ? 2 : 1), $data);
   }
   # have we got enough data?
   if ($n === $wanted) {
       break;
   }
}

        $this->content = Template::Load('user_rankingsdm', array('rankings' => $content));
    }
```

Comment: What do you need to do exactly? And there is no need to copy / reverse your whole array just to get the last xx lines.

Comment: You can use [fgets()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) to read a line at a time (or specified amount of bytes).  Although, for a 1 MB file, what kind of performance impact are you worried about?

Comment: I understand, so the file is around 6,000 lines, is the `file()` good enough for these kind of files which are approximately 1 mb up to 2 mb at maximum ? The page could be loaded a lot of times to display the latest lines, will it effect any performance actually since as you said the file doesn't seems big enough to worry??

Comment: Really comes down to how frequently this file is getting accessed.  6,000 lines seems like a lot, but PHP can rifle through that fairly quickly - at least in respect to simply seeking though the file.  However that said, what exactly is it that you are trying to achieve by moving through the file faster. Are you looking for specific rows?

Comment: It's a death log script for a game. And it can be accessed by a lot of users to check the log page of the latest 21 kills/deaths). The function grabs info from the last 21 lines from this file. Do you believe that it can affect the performance if its being accessed by a lot of users to check out the log and should I find a better way to read the lines instead of `file()` ?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to consider a database for this.  You could store your records and access the last _n_ records instead of worry about files.

Comment: I can't as stated. My application is writing this specific info only into this text file. It's hard built-in into it. So, my last option is just to use the best possible way to make sure if a lot of people access the log page that it wont be overload by requesting always the latest 21 lines from this text file ...

Comment: Well, if you are that worried about it and you expect this file to grow your best choices are to either: A) use a database (it is better for this sort of thing) or B) create a file management system that will create new files with recent information when a file gets too big.

Comment: No, I am not worried about that. The file is being recreated everyday at 00:00. I am just worried during the day if the file is around 1 mb and the log page is accessed by a lot of people .. will it somehow overload because it will read the file over and over for each page access OR for 1 mb file (5,000 - 6,000 lines) it should be fine even if a lot of people access the log page? ?

Answer (score 0):

I tuned the question's code a bit for performance. On my server, inverting the array takes about 0.7ms while the loop requires about 0.2ms.
so `$lines = array_reverse($lines);` is dropped in the solution below.

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<1000;$i++) {
    $lines[] = '1,42,16, 201,stackoverflow_user, 1, 6762160, 39799, 9817242, 6762160, 39884, 10010545,stackoverflow_user, 2, 1351147, 1165, 483259, 1351147, 1115, 241630, 0';
    $lines[] = '1,46,27, 201,[stackoverflow_user | stackoverflow_userother], 1, 4078465, 286991, 1594830, 4078465, 287036, 1643156,stackoverflow_user, 2, 1357147, 1115, 241630, 1357147, 1065, 120815, 0';
}
$lines_count = count($lines) - 1;
$content = [];
for ($i=$lines_count; $i > $lines_count - 21; $i--) {
   $l = $lines[$i];
   $content[] = $l;
}
print_r($content);
```

working example: https://eval.in/207364

Comment: Is it possible to help me out implement your suggestion into my existing code ? Will be greatly appreciated and let me accept the answer